# Change google map center on ajax success

Tags: php, ajax, google-maps

I'm using google maps for my real estatement script. The script that works google map is below.

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
var map;
    var marker;
    var coordinates = '';
  function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.070778,29.057808),

      zoom: 14,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
   };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-ajax'), mapOptions);
       google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
          var lat = event.latLng.lat().toFixed(6);
          var lng = event.latLng.lng().toFixed(6);
          createMarker(lat, lng);
          getCoords(lat, lng);
       });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

There's no problem on creating map. When user select city, state and neighborhood i'm using geocode api to get latitude and longtiude from address on my ajax page. There is no problem here either. But when i try set new center for map, there's no response lthough i have correct lat and lang. It still show me default lang and lat for center.

```
$('select[name="ads_neighborhoods"]').change(function() {
        var city = $("select[name='ads_city'] option:selected").html();
        var county = $("select[name='ads_county'] option:selected").html();
        var area = $("select[name='ads_area'] option:selected").html();
        var neighborhoods = $("select[name='ads_neighborhoods'] option:selected").html();

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajax/map.php',
            data:{'city':city, 'county':county, 'area':area, 'neighborhoods': neighborhoods},
            success:function(result){
                var data = result;
                var coordinates = new Array();
                var coordinates = data.split(",");
                map.setCenter({
                    lat : coordinates[0],
                    lng : coordinates[1]
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried `map.panTo({lat : coordinates[0], lng : coordinates[1]})` give it a go and let me know if it works for you

Comment: When i tried map.panTo() it gives an error. "not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number" And i solved problem with this error. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

There was no error on console while i try with my default code. But when I tried WebCode.ie 's code, an error appeard "not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number".

I used parseFloat() function for lat/lang that comes from ajax call. Then I combine with map.panTo() function. It worked.

```
<script>
    $('select[name="ads_neighborhoods"]').change(function() {
        var city = $("select[name='ads_city'] option:selected").html();
        var county = $("select[name='ads_county'] option:selected").html();
        var area = $("select[name='ads_area'] option:selected").html();
        var neighborhoods = $("select[name='ads_neighborhoods'] option:selected").html();

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajax/map.php',
            data:{'city':city, 'county':county, 'area':area, 'neighborhoods': neighborhoods},
            success:function(result){
                var data = result;
                var coordinates = new Array();
                var coordinates = data.split(",");
                var lat = parseFloat(coordinates[0]);
                var lng = parseFloat(coordinates[1]);
                map.panTo({lat : lat, lng : lng});
                map.setZoom(14);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```